# Are there dual-process IQ tests?

Tags: measurement, intelligence, test, iq, behavioral-economics

I mean tests that try to measure [system 1 and system 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_process_theory) performance separately, but more than [short lists of trick questions](https://www.vanityfair.com/news/2011/12/kahneman-quiz-201112) which unfortunately [seem](http://evonomics.com/please-not-another-bias-the-problem-with-behavioral-economics/) to make the bulk of the empirical work in this dual-process area.

I can see that measuring system 2 might be more difficult because it usually requires background in math etc., which usually are outside the purview of pure IQ testing...

Also, I'm aware that widely used IQ tests like [WAIS have subscales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wechsler_Adult_Intelligence_Scale#WAIS-III) like verbal vs non-verbal (aka "performance"--confusing name if you ask me) which are futher subdivided into fine-grained tasks-oriented measures like working memory or picture completion (to pick some examples). But it's unclear to me how these would [load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis) into a system-1 or system-2 paradigm.

Comment: I see there's some recent but still prelimiary work in this area https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/rationality-quotient I'm not sure they come up with an actual test.

Comment: My impression is that you have to design them yourself e.g. creating bottlenecks through use of distractor task. The point of such an enterprise is to determine the underlying structure of the cognitive machinery, I'm not sure calling it an iq test is appropriate